# Doing a proxy pass server on apache to tomcat+liferay

Tags: apache, tomcat, liferay

I have three sites hosted on liferay, and they use only one portal instance, therefore only one tomcat host.

I configured the virtual host properties on liferay, so when I type www.domain1.com, it goes to the right site.
However, when I type domain1.com, without the www prefix, it goes to the default liferay site.

One solution that I got was to do a proxy and rewrite server with apache 2, with mod_proxy_http and mod_rewrite modules.

The sites like domain1.com are rewritten to www.domain1.com, and I do a proxy pass like this:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8085
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8085
```

The tomcat server listens to the 8085 port, and apache listens to 8080.

But when the proxy pass goes on, I get a 403 - forbidden status.

I don't have a site hosted on apache, and I think that's why I got this status.
But I don't want to have any sites on apache, because the sites are on tomcat.

Is there a way to do this proxy setup without hosting a site on apache? Or maybe hosting a 
"dummy" site, just to get the proxypass to work.

Specs:

Liferay 6.1
, Tomcat 7.0.27
, Apache 2.x
, Ubuntu Server 12.04

Best Regards!

Guilherme

Answer (score 0):

try it without "/"

```
ProxyPass http://localhost:8085
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8085
```

or, maybe, you can do it with tomcat configuration: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Host_Name_Aliases